# Could someone give me an example of a .htaccess that would remove www?

Tags: linux, .htaccess

Could someone give me an example of a .htaccess that would remove www from http:// and https:// ?

I want to remove the www from BOTH ssl & www:80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) //%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I've just tried using this and the site went into a redirect loop which returns this URL: www.example.com/example.com/example.com/example.com/example.com/example.com/example.com/example.com/example.com/index.html